# GraphQL Directive requires its own query result as a variable. What is a smarter way to do this?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I've been in a feedback loop of trying to figure this out (new to GraphQL + Apollo). I got my directive "working" (the boolean does change the part of the fragment that is called, as intended). The problem is in order to write the expression that returns my directive variable, I need the resulting query that the directive is being called on! I don't know how to break this contradiction and am throwing the towel in in hopes that someone more experienced can point me in a better direction.

Here's the query and the hook it's being called on:

```
export const getDatasetPage = gql`
  query dataset($datasetId: ID!, $editTrue: Boolean!) {
    dataset(id: $datasetId) {
      id
      created
      public
      following
      starred
      ...DatasetDraft //editTrue omits a piece of this fragment if user !hasEditPermissions
      ...DatasetPermissions
      ...DatasetSnapshots
      ...DatasetIssues
      ...DatasetMetadata
      ...DatasetComments
      uploader {
        id
        name
        email
      }
      analytics {
        downloads
        views
      }
      onBrainlife
    }
  }
  ${DatasetQueryFragments.DRAFT_FRAGMENT}
  ${DatasetQueryFragments.PERMISSION_FRAGMENT}
  ${DatasetQueryFragments.DATASET_SNAPSHOTS}
  ${DatasetQueryFragments.DATASET_ISSUES}
  ${DatasetQueryFragments.DATASET_METADATA}
  ${DATASET_COMMENTS}
`

// IDEAL CONDITION TO CHECK WRITE PERMISSIONS (won't work because dataset is required //prop...which is the result of the query)

// const editTrue = (dataset) => {
//   const user = getProfile()
//   return (user && user.admin) ||
//     hasEditPermissions(dataset.permissions, user && user.sub)
// } 

export const DatasetQueryHook = ({ datasetId, editTrue }) => {
  const {
    data: { dataset },
    loading,
    error,
  } = useQuery(getDatasetPage, {
    variables: { datasetId, editTrue },
  })
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner text="Loading Dataset" active />
  } else {
    if (error) Sentry.captureException(error)
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary error={error} subject={'error in dataset page'}>
        <DatasetQueryContext.Provider
          value={{
            datasetId,
          }}>
          <DatasetPage dataset={dataset} />
        </DatasetQueryContext.Provider>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    )
  }
}

const DatasetQuery = ({ match }) => (
  <ErrorBoundaryAssertionFailureException subject={'error in dataset query'}>
    <DatasetQueryHook datasetId={match.params.datasetId} editTrue={editTrue} />
  </ErrorBoundaryAssertionFailureException>
)
...
```

After reading tons of gql docs, I'm just frustrated that after finally managing to implement a directive on a piece of a fragment, I'm met with the challenge that the query itself produces a crucial piece of data that determines what that directive is.

To add some context, I'm basically trying to omit certain files being queried when a user doesn't have write permissions to them. Currently, they're being queried for all users despite not being displayed and thus causing hefty load times.

Comment: There's no way to reference some part of a query's response and use it as input in that same query. You'd have to split the request into two separate requests that are fired sequentially.

Comment: @Daniel Rearden You're right - and that's what I don't know how to do. Are you saying I fire a first query to fetch dataset and pass it into an expression that evals the variable for a directive in a second query? Wouldn't that still consume the same bandwidth client-side though? And your directive advice worked - it is effective when hardcoding the boolean for tests. Thanks.

Comment: Put plainly, if you have some field (let's call it `A`) and you want to pass it as a value to some argument (like the `if` argument on the `@skip` directive), you have to fetch that field first, parse the response to get the value client-side and then make a second request that uses `A` as an input. There's no way to do that with a single request.

Comment: Whether splitting it up into two requests like that will be *better* than just having a single, potentially slower query is completely contextual. But what I can definitely say is there's currently no way to do that within a single request in GraphQL.

Comment: You've helped a ton here - I think two separate requests might be the best option for the sake of readability and my own sanity. I'm going to try this and post my solution once I figure it out.

Comment: @DanielRearden I tried writing it in two separate queries - I'm not exactly sure how to store the response from the first query. The docs get a bit confusing around this subject. I tried using compose() to no avail. Is there a specific parse method that I should use?

Edit: I'm also trying to edit the resolver itself to check for edit permissions on the draft files subfield. Dunno if that's a viable solution though...